# replacing a cell on the fly in a static UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

in an App I am writing, i have a form built using storyboard around a UITableView with static cells in a UITableViewController. The table has 6 rows that collects different bits of information. Row 0,3,4,5 have textfield/textview/labels to collect/display some information, row 1 has a UICollectionView with a dozen or so icons. row 2 has a height of 50 but is empty for now.

[image]

this setup works well but i am trying to add some functionality and i am stumped.
depending on what I select in the UICollectionView (in row 1), i would like to load one of a number of different cells in row 2

for example, if i click on the 2nd icon (blood pressure), the cell to load in row 2 will be used to input the systolic and diastolic values. if I click on the 3rd icon (temperature), the cell to load in row 2 will be used to input the temperature, etc...

i've designed the cells in separate class files of UITableViewCell and the corresponding xib files. i know how to register them using

```
   tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "myBPTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "myBPTableCell")
```

just not sure where to put the logic to update the table on the fly.

```
   if eventTypeCollectionIndex == 4 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myBPTableCell", for: indexPath) as! myBPdTableCell
        return cell
    }
```

i was thinking in

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

but since this function has to return a cell, i am not sure how to return the pre-existing cells for anything other than row 2

thanks
Sami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to define different cases in the cell for row at index method. And then when the user taps a button, reload the cell that you would want to change.

You would either use [reload rows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows) or `self.tableView.reloadData()`

So for example:

```
var didTap = false

func buttonTapped() {
  didTap = true
  // Reload table
}
```

And then either use a different nib for the cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  if didTap {
    // show new appearance
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myBPTableCell", for: indexPath) as! myBPdTableCell
    return cell
  } else {
    // show original
    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myBPTableCell2", for: indexPath) as! myBPdTableCell2
    return cell2
  }
}
```

Or you could update the properties of the same nib class:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myBPTableCell", for: indexPath) as! myBPdTableCell
  if didTap {
    // show new appearance
    cell.backgroundColor = .white
  } else {
    // show original
    cell.backgroundColor = .black
  }
  return cell
}
```

Edit based on comment:

You can also just do the following, where you have one cell for row 2 and then another cell for the other rows:

```
if indexPath.row == 2 {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myBPTableCell", for: indexPath) as! myBPdTableCell

    if didTap {
       cell.backgroundColor = .white
    } else {
       cell.backgroundColor = .black
    }

    return cell
} else {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myOtherCell", for: indexPath) as! myOtherCell
    return cell
}
```

Comment: thank you... i was thinking along the same lines but not sure how to handle the `else` portion of code (i.e show original) . how do i return the original cell designed in the storyboard ?

Comment: @SamiKhoury I updated my answer. You could have two different nibs for the cell and return whichever you want. Or you can use the same class and just change the properties (like backgroundColor) based on which one you need.

Comment: thanks for the updated piece but i believe this assumes that myBPTableCell is common throughout my table which it isn't. i only want to load myBPTableCell at IndexPath.row == 2  when didTap. otherwise don't change anything else in the table. since i only have 6 rows , i guess i can define a nib for each one and use the technique in your second code segment (if indexpath.row == 0, return cell0, else if indexpath.row == 1, return cell 1..)  and integrate the didTap logic for indexPath.row ==2. i was hoping to avoid this route .

Comment: many thanks for the follow-up, really appreciate it. i uploaded an image of my view controller in the OP. using your last suggestion, in my cellForRowAt, i will have to implement a `case` for every cell in my table since there isn't a way to tell this function _return the cell i designed in storyboard_.

Comment: @Sami just give the cell in storyboard a different identifier and use it in the dequeue

Comment: thank you Wyetro for your help. i was able to achieve what i want but only with a dynamic UITableView not static. can't dequeue a cell designed in IB. it is more complicated now since i need to have a XIB for every cell in my table but it is working. if there is a way with a static table, happy to reconsider and greatly appreciated,